# How to stop a linux server from beeping when a RAID HDD has failed

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive

A HDD has just failed on a linux server (Red Hat Linux release 9) we support. Not a big problem since it's on a RAID (MegaRAID SCSI). We're now in the process of getting a new one to replace it. In the meanwhile, however, the server is constantly beeping and annoying the hell out of everyone there.

Since I have remote ssh access I was wondering if there was a way to get it to shut up, preferably via the command line, until we fix the problem.

Comment: This is likely to be very specific to your hardware, maybe in the BIOS somewhere, possibly in the utility for the megaraid card? The other option would be to disconnect the PC speaker. They usually connect to the motherboard near the power switch and such.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to LSI's website and download the CLI tool for your RAID card.  Depending on the driver you're using (the one from LSI or the default one in the kernel) you can do just about anything, including turning off the alarm.

```
MegaCli -AdpSetProp AlarmSilence -a0
```

or 
 MegaCli -AdpSetProp AlarmSilence -a1 (depending on which slot is installed)

Answer (score 0):

The beeping is off the RAID card, you will need to access the card to turn it off. I would check with your vendor to see if there are management utilities to do this, I know it can be done in Dell OpenManage so I would assume there is a utility out there to do this for other systems. Otherwise you'll need to reboot and go into the RAID bios to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/megaraid/) suggests `megaraid -alarm -silence` is what you want.